# How to add SKVideoNode to ARKit-SceneKit in iOS 11?

Tags: sprite-kit, scenekit, ios11, arkit

Is there a way to add SKVideoNode to ARKit scene(Scenekit)? I tried adding SKVideoNode as SCNPlane geometry diffuse contents but it is not working,

```
    let videoNode = SKVideoNode(fileNamed: "0.mov")
    videoNode.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 100)
    videoNode.alpha = 0.8
    videoNode.play()
    self.videoNode = videoNode

    let plane = SCNPlane(width: 0.05, height: 0.05)
    let newMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    newMaterial.isDoubleSided = true
    newMaterial.diffuse.contents = self.videoNode
    plane.materials = [newMaterial]
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: plane)

    parent.addChildNode(node)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SKNode` is not one of the [supported types for SceneKit material property contents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395372-contents). Neither are any of its subclasses.

If you want to get SpriteKit content mapped onto a SceneKit material, the way to do it is to set an `SKScene` as the material property contents. That scene can then contain any number or type of SpriteKit nodes.

Comment: Can you please share some sample code on how to do it? I tried implementing the way you have mentioned but the video is not displaying properly. It just blinks and displays some colors but not the actual video. It looks like it is playing the video in the background but there is a layer applied on top thus blurring the whole video.

Comment: Show that code. And the screen grabs of the problem. Rickster is THE Man, but don't assume he's a mind reader.

Comment: @yaali I had the exact same issue. Fixed by setting a size to my Sprite Kit Scene when I created it: `let spriteKitScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 640, height: 480))`

I hope that fixes your issue!

Comment: Also note that in recent versions of SceneKit using a `SKScene` and a `SKVideoNode` is not necessary to play videos. You can directly set the `AVPlayer` as the contents of a `SCNMaterialProperty` instance.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue. Fixed by setting a size to my Sprite Kit Scene when I created it:
`let spriteKitScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 640, height: 480))`

I hope that fixes your issue!